# SQL Query if today is X days before database date

Tags: mysql

I am using this SQL Query:

```
SELECT * from reminders where status <> 'c' AND user = '".$InternalUserResult["sequence"]."' AND duedate_date = '".date("Y-m-d")."' ";
```

it selects rows from a table based on the status and if the duedate_date is set today

i have 3 other columns in the table called `duedate_time`, `remind_user_1` and `remind_user_2`

lets say in this example

```
remind_user_1 = 4
remind_user_2 = days
```

how can i add into my query *if today is 4 days before the due date *

and as another example,

```
remind_user_1 = 1
remind_user_2 = hour
```

the query i want to say:

```
if today is 1 hour before the duedate_date + duedatetime
```

Comment: the question applies for MySQL and SQL Server both or just for one of them? Please update the question and keep just one tag if the case, that would simplify things..

Answer (score 2):

The DATEDIFF function can be used in the where clause. In this case, the additional condition looks like:

```
AND DATEDIFF(duedate_date,CURDATE()) = 4
```

Comment: please check my update including the time column too

Answer (score 0):

To get 4 days before date use `SUBDATE` function in mysql. e.g.

```
SELECT SUBDATE(NOW(),4);
```

Comment: check my update which includes using the time column too

Comment: @Charles your problem in not so clear. Can you please tell us exactly what do you want?

Comment: take a look at my question again, does that make sense?

Comment: does it make sense now?

Comment: of if i can not add this into the query and just use an if statement in PHP?

Comment: @Charles still there is doubt in your question. As in my answer you can subtract days from any date and can get 4 days before date.